Null Lebesgue measure number set generates null measure domain?
Suppose that $D\subset [0,\infty)$ is a set of null measure.
Is it true that the set $\mathcal{D}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^N\ |\ |x|=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+\dots+x_N^2}\in D\}$ has also null Lebesgue measure?

Yes. Use polar coordinates in $\mathbb R^{N}$.
